# scripts to display prodCount on each category list

Tags: php, mysql, count, echo, product

I need your help to solve my problem in displaying a product count on web page.

I am re-using an example from a book for my website and modifying it to reflect a count on each category.

The current result in the display web page shows the count reflected for both categories as 3 rather than Category A = 3 and Category B = 1.

**CURRENT DISPLAY WEB PAGE**

CATEGORY
A (3)
B (3)

should be:

CATEGORY
A **(3)**
B **(1)**

Below are the ff:

**MYSQL  TABLES**

Category table

```
╔═══════════════════════════╗
║ CategoryID | CategoryName ║
╠═══════════════════════════╣
║ 1 | A                     ║
║ 2 | B                     ║
╚═══════════════════════════╝
```

Product table

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════╗
║ ProductID | CategoryID | ProductName ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1 | 1| Num0ne                        ║
║ 2 | 1 | NumTwo                       ║
║ 3 | 1 | NumThree                     ║
║ 4 | 2 | NumFour                      ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════╝
```

//php script

```
<?php
function get_categories() { 
global $db; 
     $query = 'SELECT * FROM categories 
               ORDER BY categoryID'; 
try { 
  $statement = $db->prepare($query); 
  $statement->execute(); 
  $result = $statement->fetchAll(); 
  $statement->closeCursor(); 
  return $result; 
} catch (PDOException $e) { 
display_db_error($e->getMessage()); 
    }  
}

function get_product_count_per_category( ) {
global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT productID, productName,
              (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products
              WHERE products.categoryID = categories.categoryID) 
              AS productCount 
              FROM categories
              ORDER BY categoryID';

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':category_id', $category_id);
$statement->execute( );
$result = $statement->fetchAll( );
$statement->closeCursor( );

$product_count = $result[0]['productCount']; 
return $product_count;
```

// get list of categories and display count

```
switch (action) {
  case 'list_products' :
    $categories = get_categories( );
    $product_count = get_product_count_per_category( );
    break;
}
 ?>

<html>

  <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>      
  <li>
    <a href="<?php echo $app_path . 
      'catalog?action=list_products' . 
      '&amp;category_id=' . $category['categoryID']; ?>">

    <?php echo $category['categoryName']  ." ("  .  $product_count . “ )” ;?>
    </a>
  </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>

</html>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT count(*), CategoryID
from Product
inner join Category
on Product.CategoryID = Category.CategoryID
group by CategoryID
```

Comment: Hello Oli<br/>  Thank you for your response.  I have no problem on mysql script.  My biggest problem is how can I echo my $product_count.